# Resume the loop while Iterating Json object from the specific row where it left off after token expired

Tags: python, json

I have below JSON file. I have to iterate over each json object and take the client ID and call an API with that client ID. Now the problem is my token expires after iterating over few objects.I want to resume the iteration where it left off when the token expired i.e from the same clientID where it stopped when the token expired.

```
[
    {
        "ClientList": [
            {
                "ClientId": "80801",
                "ClientName": "XYZ"
            },
            {
                "ClientId": "321801",
                "ClientName": "ABC"
            },
            {
                "ClientId": "214325",
                "ClientName": "TRE"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My current code looks like below :

```
    import json
    import pandas as pd
    import requests
    import time
    
    with open('client_file.json') as f:
        d = json.load(f)
    
    jsonList = []
    failed_counter = 1
    success_counter = 1
    start = time.time()
    for item in d:
        for innerItem in item['ClientList']:
            url = "url-goes-here{innerItem['ClientId']}"
            print(url)
            payload = {}
            headers = {
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer token',
            'IntegratorKey': '',
            'Cookie': ''
            }
    
            try:
                response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
                if response.status_code == 500:
                    print('Status Code - ',response.status_code)
                    err = json.loads(response.text)
                    print(err['ErrorMessage'])
                    if err['ErrorMessage'] == 'Session already expired.':
                        print('Id = ', innerItem['ClientId'])
                        break
                    break
                elif response.status_code == 200:
                    print(response.text)
                    success_counter = success_counter + 1
                    print('success count = ',success_counter)
                    jsonList.append(json.loads(response.text))
                else:
                    print('Response status = ',response.status_code)
                    err = json.loads(response.text)
                    print(err['ErrorMessage'])
                    failed_counter = failed_counter + 1
                    print('Failed Count = ',failed_counter)
            
            except Exception as error:
                print(error)
    
    end = time.time()
    length = start - end
    print(length)
    
    with open('create_file.json', 'w') as outfile:
        #json.dump(d,outfile)
        json.dump(jsonList, outfile ,indent=4)
```

Comment: What you show is not JSON

Comment: How are you generating the Token? Is it a Python script?

Comment: Token I have to generate from an external webpage and copy it here manually.

Comment: You can discard the processed Objects from the JSON and save the remaining in a JSON file with the same name. After you get the new token, you can rerun the same script to resume from where you stopped earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By resume, I assume you meant to run the script again, with resume. If that is the case, my approach would be

1. Load the JSON
2. Check for the existence of a "last-failed" file. If that does not exist, we start from the beginning of the list
3. If the last-failed file exist, the last run ended up with a token expiration, we need to start from a specific client ID
4. Call the API for each client
5. If token expired, save the client ID into a last-failed file and break out of the loop
6. Otherwise, we do not see any token expiration, we delete the last-failed file

Code:

```py
import itertools
import json
import pathlib
import random

LAST_FAILED_PATH = pathlib.Path("last_failed.txt")


def get_clients(data):
    for outter in data:
        yield from outter["ClientList"]


def get_clients_starting_from(data, client_id: str):
    return itertools.dropwhile(
        lambda client: client["ClientId"] != client_id, get_clients(data)
    )


def call_api(client):
    print(f"API with {client=}")

    # Simulate expiration (20% chance)
    if random.choice([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]) == 0:
        # Expired, save off the client ID
        with open(LAST_FAILED_PATH, "w") as stream:
            stream.write(client["ClientId"])
        return "Expired"
    else:
        return "OK"


def main():
    """Entry"""
    with open("client_file.json") as stream:
        data = json.load(stream)

    # Should we resume or start from the beginning of the list
    if not LAST_FAILED_PATH.exists():
        clients = get_clients(data)
    else:
        with open(LAST_FAILED_PATH) as stream:
            last_failed_id = stream.read()
        clients = get_clients_starting_from(data, client_id=last_failed_id)

    # Call the API for each client.
    # Stop the loop when we encounter an expiration
    for client in clients:
        result = call_api(client)
        print(f"--> {result}")
        if result == "Expired":
            break
    else:
        # All is well, reset the last failed
        LAST_FAILED_PATH.unlink(missing_ok=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Notes

- The `get_clients()` function will loop through the data structure and generate a list of clients. This is a helper which simplify our loops
- The `get_clients_starting_from()` will loop through the data structure and drop those clients which were succeeded (token not expired)
- The `else` clause which belongs to the `for` loop will execute only when we did not break from that loop.
- I don't know much about your API, so I simulate with `call_api()`, which has 20% chance of encounter a token expiration

Here are a few interactions. Note how when we see an expiration, the next run will resume:

```
% python main.py
API with client={'ClientId': '0', 'ClientName': 'X'}
--> OK
API with client={'ClientId': '1', 'ClientName': 'X'}
--> OK
API with client={'ClientId': '2', 'ClientName': 'X'}
--> OK
API with client={'ClientId': '3', 'ClientName': 'X'}
--> OK
API with client={'ClientId': '4', 'ClientName': 'X'}
--> OK
API with client={'ClientId': '5', 'ClientName': 'X'}
--> OK
API with client={'ClientId': '6', 'ClientName': 'X'}
--> Expired

% python main.py
API with client={'ClientId': '6', 'ClientName': 'X'}
--> OK
API with client={'ClientId': '7', 'ClientName': 'X'}
--> OK
API with client={'ClientId': '8', 'ClientName': 'X'}
--> Expired

% python main.py
API with client={'ClientId': '8', 'ClientName': 'X'}
--> OK
API with client={'ClientId': '9', 'ClientName': 'X'}
--> Expired

% python main.py
API with client={'ClientId': '9', 'ClientName': 'X'}
```

Comment: Wow. Good approach, Thanks for this answer.